# Creation of XSS vulnerable web page

Tags: javascript, html, security

I want to create a XSS vulnerable web page which execute script entered in input box. Here I have written this code but whenever I enter script nothing happens.

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeThis(){
    var formInput = document.getElementById('theInput').value;
    document.getElementById('newText').innerHTML = formInput;
    localStorage.setItem("name","Hello world!!!");
}
</script>

<p>You wrote: <span id='newText'></span> </p> 

<input type='text' id='theInput' value='Write here' />
<input type='button' onclick='changeThis()' value='See what you wrote'/>
</body>

</html>
```

Please help. How should I modify the code?

Update: I was trying to do reflected XSS. According to me if I enter a script in input It should execute. This will happen only when I am not checking that user has entered a valid input or not and taking actions not to execute script.

Here is a web page `www.insecurelabs.org/task/Rule1` which is XSS vulnerable when ever I type a script like: `<script> alert("hell"); </script>` in input field script executes.

I want to know what is the main difference between that and what I am doing?

Comment: XSS is when an attacker can inject *persistent* HTML into a page. Modifying the page directly isn't XSS. Anyone can do that at any time from the developer console.

Comment: No, I am trying Refelected XSS. You might want to look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: reflected XSS relies on injecting script via a query-string. Your form should just make a GET request to the same page, and have JavaScript analyze `window.location.search` for the RXSS data.

Comment: @Naman I'd recommend to edit your question to be more specific, and clarify what you mean exactly by xss or even reflected xss.

Comment: I have given some more explanation about the problem.

Comment: @Naman, look at that example you linked.  The difference is you're setting the `innerHTML` based on the `value` of an input (which an attacker can't control) and the reference you linked is embedding the value onto the page based on the URL (which an attacker can provide to a user for them to click).

Comment: [Here's a link to see what I mean.](http://www.insecurelabs.org/task/Rule1?query=%3Cscript%3Ealert('Oooo%20scary')%3C/script%3E)  Just by clicking this link, you're allowing me to execute my arbitrary script on that page.

Comment: If all you want is to execute code typed in the input, try my answer. It will work if you don't use `<script>` and `</script>` in the code you type/paste.

Answer (score 3):

If you use innerHTML to inject a script tag... the script won't run!

What you could do instead is inject an image with an onload event handler:

```
<img src="someImage.gif" onload="alert('hacked!')" />
```

[Update] About your last question: the main difference is that you are using innerHTML, while the insecurelabs page is using jQuery.html(). The jQuery approach will run the script.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wqqWt/

Comment: @zzzzBov right, but based on the code posted, I believe the OP actually means script injection.

Comment: @zzzzBov, he never said it was.  This does provide a resolution to the "nothing happens" situation which will allow OP to get over the hump continue on his exploration.  ;-)

Comment: Based on what OP wrote, he actually wants XSS, the code he's tried is only script injection.

Comment: @Naman I have updated my answer to address your last question.

Answer (score -2):

Just [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) the code:

```
function changeThis(){
    var formInput = document.getElementById('theInput').value;
    eval(formInput);
}
```

Comment: I know it's not, but it does what the OP is asking (unless you're supposed to type an url in the input field, then Christophe has the answer).

Comment: Okay, so I guess one downvote is for answering what's being asked, despite the inaccuracies on the OP language; the second one would be what, "eval is evil"?

Comment: Downvote because your method is functionally irrelevant. Having code run inadvertently because you assumed the input was only markup is completely different than actively evaluating an input you deem to be code. It's negligence versus intent.

Comment: @Travis I'm not assuming anything, look at the first sentence on the OP: *I want to create a xss vulnerable web page and which execute a script entered in input box*

Comment: @bfavaretto, the key difference is 'a script' and not 'script'.  If he wanted to execute script, he'd use eval.  If he wanted to execute 'a' script, he'd use the tag.  It's about the mentality and intent behind his question.

Comment: @Travis Yes, like I said a few comments above. I don't think the OP's intention is so clear (notice the grammar); it could be either.